# Can I change the battery connector on this model aircraft safely?

Tags: batteries, electrical

I am working on a project, and am required to build an autonomous glider (no propulsion).

Weight is limited to 9oz, and we are using the Pixhawk 4 mini for flight controls. The power management board (PMB) that came with the package only has XT60 plug, so it does not fit with the small batteries that I have.

Any recommendations on what I can do? I am considering de-soldering the XT60 plug on the PMB and solder a red JST plug. Is this safe to do?

Comment: PMB? But yeah, changing connectors is normal.

Comment: It would only be unsafe if your skills aren't up to the task. Since we know [nothing about you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/236542/chris?tab=profile), there's no way we can answer that for you.

Answer (score 3):

The XT60 connector is rated for 65A continuous ([per Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10474)). JST is a manufacturer that makes [lots of different connectors](http://jst.com/home21.html). In model aircraft and RC hobbies, I believe the JST [SFH connector](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=229) is quite common. This connector is only rated for 4A.

It sounds as though you have a small battery (assuming a single cell LiPo?) and a power management board that could potentially be used for much larger projects. In that case you should be OK replacing the XT60 with a smaller connector, as long as the project is never going to draw more than the connector's rated current.

If you later re-purpose the PMB for a different project, and it needs more current, don't use the under-rated connector!